# Why is composer refusing update 9.4.3 -> 9.4.5

Tags: 9, updating, composer

I am trying to update drupal core from 9.4.3 to 9.4.5.  Can anyone see why it is not working?

I executed `composer update -W drupal/core*` and it updated `drupal/core-composer-scaffold` and `drupal/core-project-message`, but not `drupal/core` nor `drupal/core-recommended`.  So next I tried `composer update -W drupal/core drupal/core-recommended`, but no luck.

Running `composer why-not -t drupal/core 9.4.5` gives:

```
drupal/core 9.4.3 Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.
└──drupal/core-recommended 9.4.3 (requires drupal/core 9.4.3)
   └──drupal/recommended-project (requires drupal/core-recommended ^9)
```

Running `composer why-not -t drupal/core-recommended 9.4.5` gives:

```
drupal/core-recommended 9.4.3 Core and its dependencies with known-compatible minor versions. Require this project INSTEAD OF drupal/core.
├──drupal/core-recommended 9.4.5 (requires drupal/core 9.4.5) (circular dependency aborted here)
└──drupal/recommended-project (does not require drupal/core but 9.4.3 is installed) (circular dependency aborted here)
```

Running `composer update -W drupal/core-recommended:9.4.5 drupal/core:9.4.5` is give a little better error message:

```
[...]
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/ckeditor_liststyle is locked to version 1.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drupal/ckeditor_liststyle 1.4.0 requires drupal/ckeditor * -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - drupal/media[dev-1.x, 1.x-dev] require drupal/core ^8 -> found drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9, 9.4.5).
    - drupal/photo_albums 1.0.2 requires drupal/media * -> satisfiable by drupal/media[dev-1.x, 1.x-dev (alias of dev-1.x)].
    - drupal/media 1.x-dev is an alias of drupal/media dev-1.x and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - drupal/photo_albums is locked to version 1.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
[...]
```

Both `drupal/ckeditor_liststyle` and `drupal/photo_albums` are installed, but neither required drupal core 8.x.

composer.json for drupal/ckeditor_liststyle

```json
{
  "name": "drupal/ckeditor_liststyle",
  "type": "drupal-module",
  "description": "This plugin adds numbered list and ordered list properties dialogs (available in context menu) in CKEditor.",
  "keywords": ["Drupal", "ckeditor", "list", "list-style"],
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "homepage": "http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor_liststyle",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Osman Gormus",
      "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/u/osman",
      "role": "Maintainer"
    }
  ],
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/ckeditor_liststyle",
    "source": "https://git.drupalcode.org/project/ckeditor_liststyle"
  },
  "require": {
    "drupal/ckeditor": "^8||^9"
  }
}
```

composer.json for drupal/photo_albums

```json
{
  "name": "drupal/photo_albums",
  "type": "drupal-module",
  "description": "Provide photo album content.",
  "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/photo_albums",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/photo_albums",
    "source": "https://www.drupal.org/project/photo_albums"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name" : "Scot Hubbard",
      "homepage" : "https://www.drupal.org/u/scothubbard"
    }
  ]
}
```

The info.yml file for ckeditor_liststyle do require drupal:ckeditor as a dependency, but this should be pointing to the core version and not be a problem:

```yml
dependencies:
  - drupal:ckeditor
```

Likewise photo_albums requires media but does not specify a version:

```yml
dependencies:
  - menu_ui
  - crop
  - node
  - user
  - media
  - pathauto
  - field_group
  - media_library
  - focal_point
  - colorbox
```

No where in my project's composer.json does it require media nor ckeditor. They do show up in the composer.lock file as `"drupal/ckeditor": "*"`, and `"drupal/media": "*"`.

composer.json for project

```json
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/twig_hash.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/views_sort_expression.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/twig-twig.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/statistics_counter.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/no_admin_destination_redirect.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/menu_token.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/ckeditor_tableselection.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/ckeditor_find.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "ckeditor/tabletoolstoolbar",
                "version": "0.0.1",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/tabletoolstoolbar/releases/tabletoolstoolbar_0.0.1.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "ckeditor/tableselection",
                "version": "4.7.2",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/tableselection/releases/tableselection_4.7.2.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "ckeditor/find",
              "version": "4.14.1",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "extra": {
                "installer-name": "ckeditor/plugins/find"
              },
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/find/releases/find_4.14.1.zip",
                "type": "zip"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "ckeditor/liststyle",
              "version": "4.8.0",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "extra": {
                "installer-name": "ckeditor/plugins/liststyle"
              },
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/liststyle/releases/liststyle_4.8.0.zip",
                "type": "zip"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "ckeditor/resize",
              "version": "4.13.0",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/resize/releases/resize_4.13.0.zip",
                "type": "zip"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "w8tcha/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin",
              "version": "1.17.8",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-WordCount-Plugin/releases/download/v1.17.8/CKEditor-WordCount-Plugin.zip",
                "type": "zip"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "jackmoore/colorbox",
              "version": "dev-master",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/archive/refs/heads/master.zip",
                "type": "zip",
                "reference": "master"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "ckeditor/a11ychecker",
              "version": "1.1.1",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/a11ychecker/releases/a11ychecker_1.1.1.zip",
                "type": "zip"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "ckeditor/balloonpanel",
              "version": "4.16.0",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://download.ckeditor.com/balloonpanel/releases/balloonpanel_4.16.0.zip",
                "type": "zip"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "enyo/dropzone",
              "version": "5.9.2",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/releases/download/v5.9.2/dist.zip",
                "type": "zip"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
              "name": "moxiecode/plupload",
              "version": "3.1.3",
              "type": "drupal-library",
              "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/archive/refs/tags/v3.1.3.zip",
                "type": "zip"
              }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/archivesspace_tokens.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/msul_staff_db_connector.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/sliker_drupal_backend.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://{HIDDEN}/msul_bootstrap4.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "ckeditor/a11ychecker": "^1.1",
        "ckeditor/balloonpanel": "^4.16",
        "ckeditor/find": "^4.14.1",
        "ckeditor/liststyle": "^4.8.0",
        "ckeditor/resize": "^4.13",
        "ckeditor/tableselection": "^4.7",
        "ckeditor/tabletoolstoolbar": "^0.0.1",
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/acl": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/address": "^1.7",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.0",
        "drupal/advanced_help": "^1.0",
        "drupal/advanced_help_hint": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/anonymous_login": "^2.0",
        "drupal/book_blocks": "^1.6",
        "drupal/bootstrap4": "^2.1",
        "drupal/bootstrap_layouts": "^5.2",
        "drupal/ckeditor_a11ychecker": "^2",
        "drupal/ckeditor_balloonpanel": "^2",
        "drupal/ckeditor_blockquote_attribution": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/ckeditor_config": "^3.0",
        "drupal/ckeditor_find": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/ckeditor_font": "^1.1",
        "drupal/ckeditor_liststyle": "^1.4",
        "drupal/ckeditor_resize": "^1.3",
        "drupal/ckeditor_specialchars": "^1.2",
        "drupal/ckeditor_tableselection": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/ckeditor_tabletoolstoolbar": "^2.0",
        "drupal/ckwordcount": "^2",
        "drupal/clientside_validation": "^3",
        "drupal/colorbox": "^1.6",
        "drupal/colorbox_load": "^1.2",
        "drupal/conditional_fields": "^4.0@alpha",
        "drupal/config_single_export": "^1.3",
        "drupal/console": "^1.9",
        "drupal/content_access": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
        "drupal/create_menus_permission": "^1.0",
        "drupal/crop": "^2.1",
        "drupal/devel": "^4.0",
        "drupal/devel_entity_updates": "^3.0",
        "drupal/diff": "^1.0",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.9",
        "drupal/entity_clone": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.1",
        "drupal/entity_usage": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/environment_indicator": "^4.0",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.1",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.1",
        "drupal/field_validation": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/flood_control": "^2.1",
        "drupal/focal_point": "^1.5",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
        "drupal/imce": "^2.2",
        "drupal/inline_responsive_images": "^2.2",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_datepicker": "^1.1",
        "drupal/kaltura_media": "^1.0",
        "drupal/ldap": "^4.0",
        "drupal/login_destination": "^2",
        "drupal/markup": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/media_bulk_upload": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/media_name": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.2",
        "drupal/menu_token": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/no_admin_destination_redirect": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/noreqnewpass": "^1.2",
        "drupal/oembed_providers": "^2.0",
        "drupal/page_manager": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/panels": "^4.6",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.6@beta",
        "drupal/photo_albums": "^1.0",
        "drupal/plupload": "^2",
        "drupal/range_slider": "^1.0",
        "drupal/realname": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.6",
        "drupal/require_revision_log_message": "^1.0",
        "drupal/scanner": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/scheduler": "^1.4",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.19",
        "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.1",
        "drupal/show_email": "^1.1",
        "drupal/sitemap": "^2",
        "drupal/statistics_counter": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/taxonomy_manager": "^2.0",
        "drupal/taxonomy_unique": "^2.3",
        "drupal/term_reference_tree": "^1.1",
        "drupal/twig-twig": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/twig_hash": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/twig_tools": "^1.3",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^3.1",
        "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/ultimate_cron": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/unused_modules": "^1.2",
        "drupal/user_expire": "^1.0",
        "drupal/viewfield": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/views_bulk_edit": "^2.5",
        "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^4",
        "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_field_view": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/views_sort_expression": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.1",
        "drupal/webform_access": "^6.0",
        "drupal/webform_handler_compare_fields": "^2.0",
        "drupal/webform_views": "^5.0@alpha",
        "drupal/workbench": "^1.1",
        "drupal/workbench_access": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/workbench_menu_access": "^1.3",
        "drush/drush": "^11",
        "enyo/dropzone": "^5",
        "jackmoore/colorbox": "dev-master",
        "moxiecode/plupload": "^3.1",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "w8tcha/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin": "^1.17",
        "web-services/archivesspace_tokens": "dev-master",
        "web-services/msul_bootstrap4": "dev-master",
        "web-services/msul_staff_db_connector": "dev-master",
        "web-services/sliker_drupal_backend": "dev-master",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/config_delete": "^1.17",
        "drupal/core-dev": "^9",
        "kint-php/kint": "^3.3",
        "symfony/debug": "^4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": false,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}/dist": [
                "enyo/dropzone"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
            ]
        },
        "patches": {
            "drupal/realname": {
              "Add Twig Support to Realname (https://www.drupal.org/project/realname/issues/3207285)":"https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-03-09/supportTwig-3207285-10.patch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have even tried removing the composer.lock file, clearing the composer cache, removing all directories (except web/sites/*) and doing a fresh composer install, but to no avail.

update:  Per suggestions from @GregW, I removed drupal/core from composer.json but it still has the exact same issue.

Comment: From this output it looks like composer.json specifies drupal/core-recommended: 9.4.3 specifically, which is why composer update won't upgrade it, but as you haven't posted a minimal example, I am just guessing.

Comment: Is drupal/recommended-project a dependency? If so, why?

Comment: I think you may be going down a rabbit hole with the modules at this point. Can you edit if your actual composer.json? If this is an older site, I suspect you have some root dependencies that are no longer needed (ie, your composer.json hasn't tracked with changes to the best practices).

Comment: @cilefen, drupal/recommended-project is drupal's recommended framework. (see [https://www.drupal.org/download]https://www.drupal.org/download).

Comment: @mpdonadio, I will try that next week.

Comment: I am well aware but it is a template. It should not actually be a listed dependency in a project. I am downvoting this question because you haven’t posted the composer.json file.

Comment: If the OP is using core-recommended, then there’s no point in also adding core to composer.json as core-recommended already defines core as a dependency (and fixes it to a specific version).

Comment: @GregW, the core-recommended was added by the drupal/recommended-project framework.  I will try removing it to see if that helps.

Comment: @cilefen, I can add the composer.json, no problem.  Just trying not to put too much in.

Comment: When I run into these package errors when updating core, I just pass the package names that are causing trouble. So try `composer update drupal/core-* drupal/ckeditor_liststyle drupal/photo_albums -W` @KevinFinkenbinder

Comment: Your composer.json shouldn’t directly include both drupal/core and drupal/core-recommended.  Core-recommended includes core as a dependency along with specific versions of other dependencies to prevent version drift.

Comment: As suggested by @GregW, I removed drupal/core from composer.json, but the exact same issue is still happening.

Comment: @KevinFinkenbinder can you post the Drupal root composer.json code please.

Comment: You need to ensure that of `drupal/core`, `drupal/core-recommended` and `drupal-recommended-project`, that only `drupal/core-recommended` is part of the `require` section of your composer.json. The others should be removed. Your messages indicate that this isn't the case.

Comment: I cannot yet add a comment so I have to answer. The same thing happened to me, I had a module installed that due to a bug prevented the upgrade to version 9.4.5 (from 9.4.3) [This](https://www.drupal.org/node/3295096) was the cause of the bug

Comment: @NoSssweat, it was added to the question before you asked.

Comment: @jaypan, look at the composer.json which is posted above, only drupal/core-recommended is part of the composer.json, but the problem persists.

Comment: @gurgolo, I wish this were an answer instead of a comment, I would mark it as the solution.  THANK YOU for solving this!

Comment: Just to let you know @KevinFinkenbinder, I'm having exactly the same issue and didn't find the reason yet.

`composer prohibits drupal/core-recommended 9.4.5`
returns
`drupal/core-recommended    9.4.5      requires         drupal/core (9.4.5)
drupal/recommended-project dev-master does not require drupal/core (but 9.4.3 is installed)`

Comment: For those that keep stating that adding drupal/core is wrong, it is not wrong, merely redundant.  Composer is quite able to keep track of requirements that are required by more than one item, as long as they are not requiring contradictory versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the reason after trying the same steps as you did!

I had installed the module "media_embed_extra" in version 1.0.0-beta1.

It caused the issue. Uninstalling and removing it from composer solved the issue.

If it's not exactly that module blocking you, see if

```
composer prohibits drupal/core-recommended 9.4.5
```

returns a module in the list of issues and try to uninstall and remove that.
My assumption is, that there's an issue with the deprecated `core:` key in that module info file:

```
name: 'Media Embed Extra'
type: module
description: 'Provides extra override options to the embedded media.'
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
package: 'Media'
dependencies:
  - media
```

Edit: Indeed `drupal/photo_albums` has the same issue:

> core: 8.x

So I'm quite sure that's the reason!
I created an issue for you and contacted the maintainer.

The original cause for this might be: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3292380

Comment: In my case, both drupal/photo_albums and drupal/ckeditor_liststyle were causing the problem.  I didn't need photo_albums so removed it.  I was able to have composer change ckeditor_liststyle to the dev version (remember to run update.php after the change).  After these two changes the update of core worked.

Comment: @JPustkuchen: I think you linked the right issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3292380, but your solution is not correct imho. It is not about the core key in info.yml, but about modules that require drupal modules in their composer.json (like drupal/ckeditor). Workaround for this is to use "provide": { "drupal/ckeditor": "*" } in your projects composer.json, see https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_media_video/issues/3300783#comment-14631983